# WebAPI Core routing issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

So, I am playing around with Web API (ASP.NET Core 2) and having routing issues.

I have several controllers such as:

SchoolController
TeacherController.

Both have Gets: `Get(int id)`

Problem is that when I run it, I get a runtime error before even actually being able to invoke the methods.

```
Attribute routes with the same name 'Get' must have the same template:
Action: MyProject.WebAPI.Controllers.SchoolController.Get (MyProject.WebAPI)' - Template: 'api/school/{id}'
Action: MyProject.WebAPI.Controllers.TeacherController.Get (MyProject.WebAPI)' - Template: 'api/teacher/{id}'
```

Why would it do this when the controllers should have their own Gets etc... so you can do:

```
/api/{controller}/1

etc... ?
```

Now, I also have another Get method, both in their controllers but with a different method signature along with a different HttpGet name i.e:

```
// TeachersController:

[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/teacher")]
public class TeacherController : Controller
{

    // GET: api/Teacher/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {

        // BLAH
    }
}
```

And for the school controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/school")]
public class SchoolController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        // BLAH
    }

    [HttpGet("SearchBasic")]
    public IActionResult SearchBasic(string schoolName, string zipCode)
    {
        // BLAH
    }
}
```

To be clear - the question is:

- Why do I get the runtime errors as soon as the web app is started?
- The get's are on different controllers, so why would there be any conflicts?

Comment: Right...you cant have actions with the same `Name` like you have in the controllers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Controllers can't have actions with the same Route `Name`. They must be unique so that the route table can differentiate them.

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions : Route Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#route-name)

> Route names can be used to generate a URL based on a specific route. Route names have no impact on the URL matching behavior of routing and are only used for URL generation. **Route names must be unique application-wide.**

*emphasis mine*

Update route names

```
[Route("api/teacher")]
public class TeacherController : Controller {

    // GET: api/Teacher/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTeacher")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id) {
        //...
    }
}

[Route("api/school")]
public class SchoolController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/school/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetSchool")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. Fixed!

Comment: I wonder If there are 2 different Controller class, why .NET core doesn't allow same Action name - Get() ? Thanks

Comment: @Cheung because they end up in the same route table the names have to be unique. Even if in another controller.

Answer (score 17):

Removing the name on get action from both controllers will solve the problem

Comment: I ran into this issue when using dotnet aspnet-codegenerator scaffolding.  The generated code adds a Name attribute to HttpGet.  Removing the Name attribute solved the problem.

Comment: Name is useful to use in CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetTeacherAsync),new {}, res) response though

Comment: What is the exact reason ??